# How to guarantee that the number of processes are properly allocated to each of the nodes

Tags: mpi

currently I am new to using IMB benchmark and wanted to make sure

whether checking the configured number of processes (np) is evenly allocated in the nodes and each cores

Currently the IMB-benchmark provides the throughput per sec based on the fixed size of message with fixed size of duration

For example like this one below.

```
$ mpirun -np 64 -machinefile hosts_infin ./IMB-MPI1 -map 32x2 Sendrecv

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       #bytes #repetitions  t_min[usec]  t_max[usec]  t_avg[usec]   Mbytes/sec
            0         1000         0.76         0.76         0.76         0.00
            1         1000         0.85         0.85         0.85         2.35
            2         1000         0.79         0.79         0.79         5.06
            4         1000         0.80         0.80         0.80        10.00
            8         1000         0.78         0.78         0.78        20.45
           16         1000         0.79         0.80         0.80        40.16
           32         1000         0.79         0.79         0.79        80.61
           64         1000         0.79         0.79         0.79       162.59
          128         1000         0.82         0.82         0.82       311.41
          256         1000         0.91         0.91         0.91       565.42
          512         1000         0.95         0.95         0.95      1082.13
         1024         1000         0.99         0.99         0.99      2076.87
         2048         1000         1.27         1.27         1.27      3229.91
         4096         1000         1.71         1.71         1.71      4802.87
         8192         1000         2.49         2.50         2.50      6565.97
        16384         1000         4.01         4.01         4.01      8167.28
        32768         1000         7.08         7.09         7.08      9249.23
        65536          640        22.89        22.89        22.89      5725.50
       131072          320        37.45        37.45        37.45      6999.22
       262144          160        65.74        65.76        65.75      7972.53
       524288           80       120.10       120.15       120.12      8727.37
      1048576           40       228.63       228.73       228.68      9168.57
      2097152           20       445.38       445.69       445.53      9410.86
      4194304           10       903.77       905.97       904.87      9259.29

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, this does not guarantee that the processes are evenly distributed to the nodes  when I configure the different  varying number of processors.

Would assigning to the specific core be possible in IMB-benchmark? or do I need to use the alternative benchmark to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that processes (mpi ranks) are allocated into nodes is something that depends on the mpi launcher (mpirun in your case), it has nothing to do with the application, although application performance will get impacted as well as application execution if using local resources such as files in local filesystems. BTW, the process pinning to specific cores is also responsibility of the mpi launcher or the mpi library.

Since you don't specify which mpi implementation you use, I strongly encourage you to look at man mpirun. Some mpirun commands allow -ppn to specify the number of processes per node. Others allow you to limit the number of slots in ymthe machinefile.

Finally, some mpi launchers offer certain levels of verbosity to show the user how the processes are mapped into the nodes.